# OpenVAS get_reports command not working with Powerfilter

Tags: xml, openvas

I want to issue an XML command to OpenVAS Manager in order to get a paginated list of reports. If I want a page size of 10 and the second page, for example, I issue the following command:

```
<get_reports filter="first=11 rows=10" />
```

But it always returns me the unpaginated list of all the reports saved on the database. What am I doing wrong? I am also unable to sort the results or filter them. All things that can be usually done by using the "filter" attribute are not working for me on the get_reports command. All other commands work well.

Answer (score 1):

We had to e-mail the OpenVAS community and they give us the solution. Instead of filter, the attribute that must be used specifically with `get_reports` command for doing pagination, filtering and sorting of the reports, is `report_filter`. An example:

```
<get_reports report_filter="first=11 rows=10" />
```

This is not specified in the OpenVAS official documentation.